# What's the best way to manipulate data in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mapreduce, underscore.js

I'm coding an app that fetches some data from Advertising platforms. My data structure looks like that:

```
{
  campaign_id: 123,
  campaign_name: SomeName,
  subcampaigns: [
    {country: Australia, impressions: 12000, cost: 12},
    {country: Australia, impressions: 14000, cost: 17},
    {country: Singapore, impressions: 10000, cost: 7},
    {country: Singapore, impressions: 7000, cost: 6}
  ]
}
```

I need to turn this into something like:

```
[{
  campaign_name: SomeName,
  country: Australia,
  impressions: 36000
  cost: 29
},
{
  campaign_name: SomeName,
  country: Singapore
  impressions: 17000
  cost: 13
}]
```

What would be the best way to do such Map-Reduce operations in NodeJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var groupedSubcampaigns = _.groupBy(data.subcampaigns, 'country');
var summator = function(memo, el) {
    return memo + el;
};
var result = _.map(groupedSubcampaigns, function(group, country) {
    return {
        campaign_name: data.campaign_name,
        country: country,
        impressions: _.reduce(_.pluck(group, 'impressions'), summator, 0),
        cost: _.reduce(_.pluck(group, 'cost'), summator, 0)
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JGk5S/) *(somehow it's hard to find a node.js online codepad with an option of including external libraries, but I guess jsfiddle will work fine in this case).*

Explanation... well, I actually believe the code is quite self-explaining here. ) First we create a hash of subcampaigns grouped by country, then we go through each item of this hash with `_.map`, reducing its `impressions` and `cost` properties with 'summator' function.

There's still a room for improvement, though: you can drop the `pluck` method and go through the collection with a single reduce, like this:

```
var summator = function(memo, el) {
    memo.impressions += el.impressions;
    memo.cost += el.cost;
    return memo;
};
var result = _.map(groupedSubcampaigns, function(group, country) {
    var aggregateObj = _.reduce(group, summator, {impressions:0, cost:0});
    return _.extend(aggregateObj, {
        campaign_name: data.campaign_name,
        country: country
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tT59L/).

Comment: Thanks man. What happens if I need to GroupBy several "fields"?

Comment: Could you give an example? At first sight, it looks like a composite key can be used in this case.

Comment: Let's say I have in the "subcampaigns" object "banner_id". And the final result I'm expecting should be: campaign_name|banner_id|country|impressions|cost

Comment: It's a bit trickier, but certainly possible: first, use a function iterator in `groupBy` (that will create a compound key: `country` + '|' + `banner_id`, for example), then extract these components off a key with `split` in `_.map`.

Comment: Thanks again. Would it be a good idea that instead of "hard coding" the object, I'll flatten the whole structure and then will perform the Map-Reduce operations? Is that a common practice? Thanks.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42582/discussion-between-tounano-and-raina77ow)